# Call a Mathematica program from the command line, with command-line args, stdin, stdout, and stderr

Tags: command-line, scripting, wolfram-mathematica

If you have Mathematica code in foo.m, Mathematica can be invoked with `-noprompt`
and with `-initfile foo.m`
(or `-run "<<foo.m"`)
and the command line arguments are available in `$CommandLine` (with extra junk in there) but is there a way to just have some mathematica code like

```
#!/usr/bin/env MathKernel
x = 2+2;
Print[x];
Print["There were ", Length[ARGV], " args passed in on the command line."];
linesFromStdin = readList[];
etc.
```

and chmod it executable and run it?  In other words, how does one use Mathematica like any other scripting language (Perl, Python, Ruby, etc)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MASH -- Mathematica Scripting Hack -- will do this.

Since Mathematica version 6, the following perl script suffices:

http://ai.eecs.umich.edu/people/dreeves/mash/mash.pl

For previous Mathematica versions, a C program is needed:

http://ai.eecs.umich.edu/people/dreeves/mash/pre6

UPDATE: At long last, Mathematica 8 supports this natively with the "-script" command-line option:

http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/mathematica-shell-scripts/

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that does not require an additional helper script. You can use the following shebang to directly invoke the Mathematica kernel:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec <"$0" || exit; read; read; exec /usr/local/bin/math -noprompt "$@" | sed '/^$/d'; exit
(* Mathematica code starts here *)
x = 2+2;
Print[x];
```

The shebang code skips the first two lines of the script and feeds the rest to the Mathematica kernel as standard input. The *sed* command drops empty lines produced by the kernel.

This hack is not as versatile as [MASH](http://ai.eecs.umich.edu/people/dreeves/mash/). Because the Mathematica code is read from *stdin* you cannot use *stdin* for user input, i.e., the functions [Input](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Input.html) and [InputString](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputString.html) do not work.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you add the Mathematica binaries to the PATH environment variable in ~/.profile,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Then you just write this shebang line in your Mathematica scripts.

```
#!/usr/bin/env MathKernel -script
```

Now you can dot-slash your scripts.

```
$ cat hello.ma
#!/usr/bin/env MathKernel -script

Print["Hello World!"]

$ chmod a+x hello.ma
$ ./hello.ma
"Hello World!"
```

Tested with Mathematica 8.0.

Minor bug: Mathematica surrounds Print[s] with quotes in Windows and Mac OS X, but not Linux. WTF?

Answer (score 4):

Try
-initfile *filename*
And put the exit command into your program

Comment: Thanks, that's an improvement over -run.  I updated the question.  I have what I think is a more complete solution that I'll post shortly.

Comment: In my mash.pl solution it turns out you do have to use -run, not -initfile.  I'm not sure why but the latter causes problems with mathematica scripts that read from files.

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution that worked for me.

Save the code in a .m file, then run it like this: MathKernel -noprompt -run “<

This is the link: http://bergmanlab.smith.man.ac.uk/?p=38

Answer (score 1):

For mathematica 7

```
$ cat test.m
#!/bin/bash
MathKernel -noprompt -run < <( cat $0| sed -e '1,4d' )  | sed '1d'
exit 0
### code start Here ... ###
Print["Hello World!"]
X=7
X*5
```

Usage:

```
$ chmod +x test.m

$ ./test.m
"Hello World!"

7
35
```