# Mathematica in batch mode from the command line on Mac OS X

Tags: command-line, macos, wolfram-mathematica

I'd like to start writing some unit tests for my Mathematica programs and control everything from the command line with some Makefiles.

It seems like Mathematica [can be run from the command line](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LaunchingMathematicaOnUnixAndLinux.html) but I can't see any basic instructions on getting started with doing this on Mac OS X — has anyone done this before?

---

**Update:**

Creating a test file like this:

```
Print["hello"];
x := 1;
y = x+1;
z = y+1;
Print["y="ToString@y];
Print["z="ToString@z];
Quit[];
```

And running it with

```
/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel -noprompt < test.m
```

is the closest I can get to some sort of batch processing. The output looks ugly, though; newlines are added for every line of the script!

```
"hello"




"y=2"

"z=3"
```

Is this the closest thing I can get to a script that can still output information to the console output? I'm only using Mathematica 6, but I hope that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Have you looked at mash: http://ai.eecs.umich.edu/people/dreeves/mash/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This, finally, gives output like I'd expect it to:

```
/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel -noprompt -run "<<test.m"
```

Makes sense, I suppose. Adding this to my `.bash_profile` allows easy execution (as in `mma test.m`):

```
mma () { /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel -noprompt -run "<<$1" ; }
```

See also [dreeves's `mash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148057/calling-a-mathematica-program-from-the-command-line-with-command-line-args-stdi/151656#151656) Perl script, which may offer advantages over this approach.

Answer (score 2):

With some experimentation, I found that `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel` can be launched from the command-line.  It doesn't seem to accept the usual `-h` or `--help` command-line flags, though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pillsy and Will Robertson for the MASH plug!  Here's the relevant StackOverflow question: [Call a Mathematica program from the command line, with command-line args, stdin, stdout, and stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148057/calling-a-mathematica-program-from)

If you don't use MASH, you may want to use the following utility functions that MASH defines.
For example, the standard Print will print strings with quotation marks -- not usually what you want in scripts.

```
ARGV = args = Drop[$CommandLine, 4];         (* Command line args.            *)
pr = WriteString["stdout", ##]&;             (* More                          *)
prn = pr[##, "\n"]&;                         (*  convenient                   *)
perr = WriteString["stderr", ##]&;           (*   print                       *)
perrn = perr[##, "\n"]&;                     (*    statements.                *)
EOF = EndOfFile;                             (* I wish mathematica            *)
eval = ToExpression;                         (*  weren't so damn              *)
re = RegularExpression;                      (*   verbose!                    *)
read[] := InputString[""];                   (* Grab a line from stdin.       *)
doList[f_, test_] :=                         (* Accumulate list of what f[]   *)
  Most@NestWhileList[f[]&, f[], test];       (*  returns while test is true.  *)
readList[] := doList[read, #=!=EOF&];        (* Slurp list'o'lines from stdin *)
```

To use MASH, just grab that perl file, [mash.pl](http://ai.eecs.umich.edu/people/dreeves/mash/mash.pl), and then make your test.m like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /path/to/mash.pl

prn["hello"];
x := 1;
y = x+1;
z = y+1;
prn["y=", y];
prn["z=", z];
```