# Calling Mathematica from OCaml program

Tags: ocaml, wolfram-mathematica

I am writing OCaml code. In part of it, I want to examine whether two arithmetic expression are equal (like x+2+y == x+2*y-y+2). Implemeting this in mathematica is straightforward, so all I want some help on executing Mathematica and get the result back in OCaml. My OS platform is Linux.

Cheers,
Z.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to use something along the lines of this:

```
let channel_to_mathematica, channel_from_mathematica = open_process "mathematica"
in
Printf.fprintf channel_to_mathematica "Tell me if this is equal ...\n";
let answer_from_mathematica = Scanf.fscanf channel_from_mathematica ... 
in
...
```

[Documentation of open_process here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html)

[Documentation of module Scanf here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Scanf.html)

Answer (score 3):

A very general answer is to write a command-line Mathematica script that takes 2 expressions (either on the command line or stdin) and outputs whether they are equal.
Then in OCaml simply call that program with a system call.

As for writing such a command-line Mathematica script, I recommend MASH (disclosure: I made MASH):
  [Call a Mathematica program from the command line, with command-line args, stdin, stdout, and stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148057/call-a-mathematica-program-from-the-command-line)